# openpyxl delete all values except the column row excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel:

```
   A      B        C             D
1  long  short  suggested_long  suggested_short
2  -2.11  5.11   #N/A           
3  -4.11  3.66   #REF!           #N/A
4  93.44  7.55   0               0
5  1256.4 966.5  563.5           #REF!
```

So, long is in cell(A1), 5.11 is in cell(B2);
I want to clear all the values in suggested_long and suggested_short but need to keep the column name rows as I need to insert data after cleaning all the values. Then the result should be:

```
   A      B        C             D
1  long  short    
2  -2.11  5.11              
3  -4.11  3.66             
4  93.44  7.55               
5  1256.4 966.5
```

I know openpyxl can do like:

```
for row in ws['C1:D5']:
  for cell in row:
    cell.value = None
```

to delete the value in the cell, but I have uncertain number of cell values in suggested_long and suggested_short. I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here, many thanks

Comment: You've got the right idea of setting these to None. But don't set all A1:D5 to None, rather look in column headers for `suggested` in set C1:D5 to None.

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo, correct it to C1 from A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for row in ws['C2:D'+str(len(ws['D']))]:
  for cell in row:
    cell.value = None
```

Comment: this is good, but in this way, the column name will also be deleted

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to adapt the answer to the specific cells you needed. Fixed it, now it should work fine :) @Michael

Comment: wow, D also will start from D2, perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Of couse, the easiest thing would be simply to delete the columns and replace the headers:

```
ws.delete_cols(3, 2)
ws["C1"] = "suggested_long"
ws["D1"] = "suggested_short"
```

Otherwise use `ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=3)`